# Why does my copied SKLabelNode show up in a different place on screen despite having the same frame and position as the original?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I created an SKLabelNode, set a few properties, and then copied it by calling `[labelNode copy]`. I haven't changed anything on the copy, and the `position` and `frame` are the same on the copy as they are on the original, but the text is showing up a few pixels above or below the original. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label's `verticalAlignmentMode` is NOT copied when you call `[labelNode copy]`. The copy had an alignment mode of `SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBaseline` even though the original was set to `SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter`. All I had to do was set the alignment mode to be the same as the original and they rendered in the same place.